# angular.element.scope() sometimes does not return scope functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, chart.js

I'm working on a site that utilizes chart.js and angularjs to build a visualization dashboard for fiscal information. The data for the visualizations are queried from a back end and stored on the page's angular factory and controller. My chart.js script then calls a scope function from the controller to retrieve the current visualization's data.

The function in the chart.js script looks like this:

```
function getData() {
    if (myChart != null) myChart.destroy();
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementbyId("angular-dashboard-container")).scope();

    console.log(scope);

    setPieChartData(scope.getPieChartData());
    setPieChartLabels(scope.getPieChartLabels());
    setPieChartColors(scope.getPieChartColors());
    setPieChartID(scope.getPieChartID());

    setTimeout(buildChart, 120);
}
```

The functions in the angularjs controller all have a similar format like this:

```
$scope.getPieChartData = function() {
    return pieChartData;
}
```

Most of the time, the data is passed to the chart.js script without a hitch, but 10 to 20% of the time, the visualization doesn't appear on the screen and the console returns this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: scope.getPieChartData is not a function at getData`

When I started logging the scope object to the console, I saw that when the function worked, the scope object listed all of the scoped functions in the page's controller. When the function returned the type error, the logged scope object had *none* of the scope functions listed and scope.$parent (as well as some other attributes) were set to `null`.

So my question is what am I not getting that's causing the script to error not all of the time, but *some* of the time? Being relatively new to angularjs, I'm assuming it's something about the DOM or how the page is being built.

For context, I'm using angularjs v1.5.8 and chart.js v2.2.2. Thanks for all the help you can provide.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.scope()` for anything. You should be injecting scope into your controller/directive/whatever. I suggest doing some [research on how scope works in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: not to mention there are chartjs angular modules available

Comment: @charlietfl I saw some of these modules earlier on in the project, but I was kind of intimidated by them due to my lack of familiarity with the tool set. I'll take another look at them now that I have a better grasp of angular and chart.js.